# NPE after upgrading JAX-WS version 2.2.1 to 2.2.8

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-ws

The application was using JAX-WS version 2.2.1 where I found issue in dealing with CustomException. Unable to generate the classes due to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions. So I changed the version of JAX WS to JAX-WS 2.2.8, the above issue got solved(the classes for CustomExceptions got created). But now I am getting the following error while trying to consume the service:

```
Dec 20, 2013 2:42:42 AM com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at server.service.SampleServiceEndpoint.getItems(SampleServiceEndpoint.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Following is my Custom exception class and Fault bean.

```
public class ConcurrencyException extends Exception {
private ConcurrencyInfoBean faultInfo;

    public ConcurrencyException(String message, ConcurrencyInfoBean faultInfo) {
        super(message);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public ConcurrencyException(String message, ConcurrencyInfoBean faultInfo, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public ConcurrencyInfoBean getFaultInfo() {
        return faultInfo;
    }
}

public class ConcurrencyInfoBean {
protected String message;

    public ConcurrencyInfoBean() {}

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String value) {
        this.message = value;
    }
}
```

For which following classes where generated:

```
package client.service.jaxws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="ConcurrencyException", propOrder={"faultInfo", "message"})
public class ConcurrencyException
{
  protected ConcurrencyInfoBean faultInfo;
  protected String message;

  public ConcurrencyInfoBean getFaultInfo()
  {
    return this.faultInfo;
  }

  public void setFaultInfo(ConcurrencyInfoBean paramConcurrencyInfoBean)
  {
    this.faultInfo = paramConcurrencyInfoBean;
  }

  public String getMessage()
  {
    return this.message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String paramString)
  {
    this.message = paramString;
  }
}

package client.service.jaxws;

import javax.xml.ws.WebFault;

@WebFault(name="ConcurrencyException", targetNamespace="http://service.server/")
public class ConcurrencyException_Exception extends Exception
{
  private ConcurrencyException faultInfo;

  public ConcurrencyException_Exception(String paramString, ConcurrencyException paramConcurrencyException)
  {
    super(paramString);
    this.faultInfo = paramConcurrencyException;
  }

  public ConcurrencyException_Exception(String paramString, ConcurrencyException paramConcurrencyException, Throwable paramThrowable)
  {
    super(paramString, paramThrowable);
    this.faultInfo = paramConcurrencyException;
  }

  public ConcurrencyException getFaultInfo()
  {
    return this.faultInfo;
  }
}

package client.service.jaxws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="concurrencyInfoBean", propOrder={"message"})
public class ConcurrencyInfoBean
{
  protected String message;

  public String getMessage()
  {
    return this.message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String paramString)
  {
    this.message = paramString;
  }
}
```

After which I am getting a NPE in Web Service endpoint class:

```
@MTOM
@WebService(name = "sampleService")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class SampleServiceEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @Autowired
    LookupService lookupService;

    @Autowired
    PersistenceService persistenceService;

    @WebMethod
    public List<Items> getItems() {
        return lookupService.getItems(); // Throws NPE
    }

    @WebMethod
    public long updateItem(@WebParam(name = "item") Item item) throws ConcurrencyException{
        return persistenceService.updateItem(item);
    }

    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
    @WebMethod
    public DataHandler downloadFaxFile(String filename){
        return  new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(filename));
    }
}
```

The request details captured using Fiddler: (Please note the version mentioned for User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01, but actually I am using 2.2.8 in server.)

```
POST http://172.16.1.17:8080/sample-server/sampleService HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: multipart/related;start="<rootpart*c42f6a20-3467-47db-9f42-2fd710e98a91@example.jaxws.sun.com>";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:c42f6a20-3467-47db-9f42-2fd710e98a91";start-info="text/xml"
SOAPAction: "http://service.server/sampleService/getItemsRequest"
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
Host: 172.16.1.17:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 461
Connection: close

--uuid:c42f6a20-3467-47db-9f42-2fd710e98a91
Content-Id: <rootpart*c42f6a20-3467-47db-9f42-2fd710e98a91@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:getItems xmlns:ns2="http://service.server/"></ns2:getItems></S:Body></S:Envelope>
--uuid:c42f6a20-3467-47db-9f42-2fd710e98a91--
```

The response captured using Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related; start="<rootpart*fd6818ff-12f2-490b-b0fe-7d99e1196491@example.jaxws.sun.com>"; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:fd6818ff-12f2-490b-b0fe-7d99e1196491"; start-info="text/xml"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 21 Dec 2013 08:30:25 GMT
Connection: close

154
--uuid:fd6818ff-12f2-490b-b0fe-7d99e1196491
Content-Id: <rootpart*fd6818ff-12f2-490b-b0fe-7d99e1196491@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body>
b5
<S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>S:Server</faultcode><faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>
2f

--uuid:fd6818ff-12f2-490b-b0fe-7d99e1196491--
0
```

Spring config files:
1. applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="server"/>

    <import resource="datasource.xml"/>
    <import resource="services.xml"/>

</beans>
```

1. services.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="lookupService" class="server.service.LookupServiceImpl">
       <property name="statusDAO" ref="statusDAO"/>
       <property name="utilDAO" ref="utilDAO"/>
       <property name="logDAO" ref="logDAO"/>
       <property name="faxHistoryDAO" ref="faxHistoryDAO"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="persistenceService" class="server.service.PersistenceServiceImpl">
       <property name="logDAO" ref="logDAO"/>
       <property name="faxHistoryDAO" ref="faxHistoryDAO"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="adminService" class="server.service.AdminServiceImpl">
       <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="reportService" class="server.service.ReportServiceImpl">
       <property name="reportDAO" ref="reportDAO"/>
   </bean>
   ```

The environment details:
jdk1.7.0_21, tomcat 7, windows 7

Comment: What NPE are you getting?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I have updated by question with the exception details

Comment: Looks like `lookupService` isn't being injected. And I thought `@Autowired` was a Spring thing, and that you do injection with different annotations in other DI frameworks. And why are you injecting into something with the `…Impl` type anyway?

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you Doanl, As suggested I have corrected my class. The DI is done with Spring, but still the error remains same.

Comment: It seems that `lookupService` bean injection still is broken. Could you provide some details on Spring config of that bean (xml or class with annotations)?

Comment: @EugeneEvdokimov I have updated the question with spring config files.

Comment: Have you [written a test](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing-goals) to see what happens with `lookupService` injection? Or at the very least looked at the startup logs?

Comment: There is a handful of similar questions on SO with the appropriate solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178237/autowiring-not-working-in-spring-jax-ws-on-jboss-as-7, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445969/using-jax-ws-webservices-with-spring-3-0-x-on-jboss-as-7-1-x, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350723/jboss-6-spring-3-0-5-jax-ws-cxf. Look at them please.

Comment: Try without `<import resource="services.xml"/>` in your `applicationContext.xml` (component scan should be sufficient).

Comment: Thank you @EugeneEvdokimov I have gone through the links it was really helpful and was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could avoid the NPE by modifying my Webservice endpoint class but not so sure whether the following solution is best or not, but it works for me:

```
@MTOM
@WebService(name = "sampleService")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class SampleServiceEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @Autowired
    LookupService lookupService;

    @Autowired
    PersistenceService persistenceService;

    @WebMethod(exclude=true)
    private void initLookupService(){
        if(lookupService == null)
            processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @WebMethod(exclude=true)
    private void initPersistenceService(){
        if(persistenceService == null)
            processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @WebMethod
    public List<Items> getItems() {
        initLookupService();
        return lookupService.getItems();
    }

    @WebMethod
    public long updateItem(@WebParam(name = "item") Item item) throws ConcurrencyException{
        initPersistenceService()
        return persistenceService.updateItem(item);
    }

    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
    @WebMethod
    public DataHandler downloadFaxFile(String filename){
        return  new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(filename));
    }
}
```